# Prestashop changing currency in numbers.json

Tags: javascript, json, prestashop

I'm trying to change the way the South Korean won is displayed in my customer's shop.

As of now, it is displayed like this:

> 44.789,00 I'd like to display it as 44.789

To achieve this I modified the numbers.json in /translations/cldr/datas/main/ko-KR

However, after saving the file, nothing changed.

At first, I made sure that my CDN and cache are disabled and that my theme is recompiled but even after making sure that's the case, and deleting the whole content of the .json file to verify that there are actual changes happening, nothing at all changed.

I now noticed, that if I edit the main--ko-KR--numbers file that is in the translations/cldr folder, it actually works. However, it changes the display of every currency if you select the Korean language. I'd rather have it only change the way the South Korean Won is displayed.

This is the content of main--ko-KR--numbers

https://codeshare.io/GkzV4V

This is the content of numbers.json in translations/cldr/datas/main/ko-KR

https://codeshare.io/a3vneL

Comment: Indeed, nothing happened ... How we're supposed to debug some code we can't see?

Comment: " I modified the numbers.json"...not much help if we can't see what it looked like before, and what it looks like now. We can't read your screen, or your requirements. We can't even read your mind.

Comment: Touché. I've added links to the related files.

Comment: What Prestashop version are you using?

Comment: @Indrė 1.7 branch ;)

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: please add your code _within the question_. There is a code editor. External links can change or even die over time, making the question meaningless to future readers. Plus there's no need to make people work harder than they need to to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You should not never touch any of files in Prestashop core.

If you just want to **remove decimals** – go to `Shop Parameters` > `General` and change `Number of decimals`.

[image]

If you want to change it **for the selected currency only**, you can edit numbers in your template like that:

```
{if isset($currency) && $currency.iso_code == 'KRW'}
    {$price|replace:',00':''}
{else}
    {$price}
{/if}
```

If you really want to change Prestashop core, you can edit `localization/kr.xml` file and change `decimals="0"`.

Comment: The problem with that is, that it removes the decimals for every currency. Which isn't desired. It's specifically requested for the South Korean Won. Not to mention that changing the decimals there, only changes the rounding. They're still displayed. Just as 00 instead of whatever amount they'd be depending on how one rounds.